# Как в Tkinter Scrollbar для таблицы treeview сделать неактивным

Tags: python, tkinter

Возможно ли в Tkinter Scrollbar для таблицы treeview сделать неактивным или убрать ползунок, но не удалять, пока получилось только полностью скрыть Scrollbar

```
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

i = 0
for item in rows:
    #Вывод строк таблицы
    tree.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=0,text='', values=(item[0],item[1]))
    i += 1

#если строк меньше 10
if i < 10:
    #убираем скролл
    scrollbar.pack_forget()
else:
    #иначе отображаем
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

tree.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Но хочется не скрывать, а сделать Scrollbar неактивным, убрать ползунок если таблица пустая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так он по умолчанию неактивен, пока не произойдет переполнения по высоте

Comment: Виджет таблицы treeview по-умолчанию переполнен и скролл активен, когда в таблице количество записей уменьшается ползунок скрола растягивается на всю высоту, а надо чтобы ползунок скрылся, а сам скроллбар остался на месте

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит попробовать вместо скроллбар заменять фреймом, который будет такого же цвета окна?

```
scrollbarHide = Frame(scrollbar, bg = "Цвет  фона")
scrollbarHide.place(relx  = 0, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.8)
```

Я использую place() - так как мне это удобней, но вы можете использовать pack()
Либо же можно попробовать такую строку:

```
#если строк меньше 10
if i < 10:
   #убираем скролл
   scrollbar.config(indicatoron = 0)
```

Но! Я не уверен что это свойство применимо к scrollbar, я знаю только за radiobutton и checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Мне подошел данный код

```
#Создание фрейма в котоый вкладывается скролл и таблица
game_frame = Frame(tk, bg="#ccc", borderwidth=1)
game_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=3, sticky=N+S+W+E, padx=8)

#Создание скрола
vsb = Scrollbar(game_frame)
vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#Создание таблицы
tree = ttk.Treeview(game_frame, style="mystyle.Treeview", yscrollcommand=vsb.set, selectmode="browse", height=17)
tree.pack(fill=BOTH)
vsb.config(command=tree.yview)
```

Благодарю за ответ!